# Users can type and edit my published post, can't figure out why

Tags: wordpress, blog-post

On my post from the first h2 tag and down if you click in the text you can type and edit the content. While it doesn't save, I don't want users to be able to do this. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I originally posted this in wordpress.stack thinking this was a wordpress issue but now i'm convinced it is my code.

http://google.com/42v70w

Comment: WPSE post here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226353/when-viewing-my-blog-post-in-browser-i-can-type-and-edit-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Wordpress default behaviour, it's either due to your theme ([the Stanley theme](http://gentsthemes.com/demo/stanleywp/)) or a plugin you are running.

I note in the code, the entire `<div>` surrounding the contents has this attribute on it:

```
<div id="contentsContainer" contenteditable="true">
```

It doesn't look like the contents are editable on the official Stanley site, so I'd hazard a guess that you have a plugin doing something like this.

If you disable all your plugins, check if the content is editable, and then re-enable each plugin one by one you should be able to determine which plugin is doing this.

Then, I'd suggest looking into that plugin's specific settings to see whether there's an option to turn this behaviour off.

For example, here's a plugin that adds this behaviour - [WP Errata](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-errata/) - are you using that plugin by any chance?

Comment: I changed the contenteditable to false in my browser and it worked. I will try   the plugin method you recommenced to see which one is causing the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I have disabled all plugins and i'm not using WP Errata and it is still an issue. Is there another way to remove this?

Comment: It must be related to your theme then. Can you search the theme files and see if the phrase `contenteditable` is in there?

Comment: Just figured it out. Thanks!